# Need help in fork() diagram

Tags: c, fork, diagram

tomorrow is my exam and i have difficulty in understanding fork() diagrams, all what i want is to correct me

```
fork()&&fork()&&fork()
```

i used this diagram

[image]

but my teacher told me that this is wrong and if u draw me this tomorrow i will give u negative marks, and he me told that this is the right one.

[image]

Comment: Ask yourself: What does the value returned by `fork` represent?

Comment: Pretend to be a computer on pen and paper. The first process calls the first fork and splits into two processes. Does the parent one call the second fork? Does the child one call the second fork?

Comment: i wanna know which one is correct

Comment: _Hint:_ Barring an error return of -1 from `fork`, It returns 0 for the child and non-zero for the parent (i.e. the `pid` of the child). Remember that an expression of the form `exprA && exprB && exprC` does "short circuit evaluation" and does _not_ evaluate `exprB` or `exprC` if `exprA` is _false_. `exprA` _will_ be _false_ for the child process. So, the second [your prof's] answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The `fork()` returns the pid of the child in parent address space, some non-negative value. While in the child address space, a 0 is returned.

The `&&` operand doesn't evaluate the rhs if the lhs is false, which is the case in the child process.

After first fork

```
Parent

    true && fork() && fork()

Child
      
          ---> never evaluated
    false && fork() && fork()
```

Comment: The second diagram (in case all forks executed successfully)

Comment: under what circumstances does this return false?

Comment: None, because it doesn't return a boolean, but it does return `0`, which is logically evaluated as false.

Answer (score 1):

`fork()&&fork()&&fork()` is equivalent to this:

```
if(fork()) {
    if(fork()) {
       fork();
    }
}
```

From the documentation for `fork()` you can read that it returns the pid of the child in the parent process, and 0 in the child process. So the second diagram is correct. No child process will invoke fork.